# describe cannot be used in Pig macro?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Using Hadoop Pig. And want to use describe on an alias to see its schema, and I want to use describe inside a Pig macro. There are unexpected character near describe issue. But when I move describe outside, it is always fine. Wondering is describe has any restrictions to be used inside Pig macro? Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an intended feature, but it is a side effect of the way macros are implemented. Pig actually has a couple of parser in it. One parses Pig Latin, the other is used by Grunt, the shell. Grunt does not know Pig Latin, but it knows to pass it on to the Pig Latin parser. Pig Latin knows nothing of Grunt.

**Describe, dump, explain, and illustrate** are implemented in Grunt, not Pig Latin. Macros are resolved (that is, replaced and written inline) by the Pig Latin parser before Grunt is called. Since the Pig Latin parser doesn't understand Grunt commands, it is complaining when it encounters them inside macros.

Refer [this](http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/125r1q4tnc/diagnostic-operators-inside-macros).